# T-SQL Updating rows with Current_timestamp

Tags: t-sql, timestamp, sql-update

Perhaps a noob question, but take this **T-SQL query** in mind:

```
UPDATE Table
SET column = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE condition
```

and it takes 1 minute. Will the column have the same Timestamp value or incremental? (as the time goes by) ?

And if you want to have the timestamp equal in all rows, is there any other option than with a defined variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will have the same value in all rows regardless of how long the query takes. The function is evaluated once per statement not once per row.

This is the case for nearly all built in functions in SQL Server the only exceptions I am currently aware of are `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` and `NEWID`

Comment: Anyways.. it would clearly 'bother' me if NEWID had been generating the same GUID ;) (or random the same valu)

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me - `rand()` does give the same value. The workaround is to use either the new `crypt_gen_random` or `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`